# How to add a class to a sub element using JS

Tags: javascript, css, dropdown, megamenu

I have a navigation menu. I want to add a class to an `<ul>` tag as .container but only if that element has class "megamenu" for example. How can I achieve it? As I will only have one dropdown as "mega menu".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".megamenu dropdown");`. Now loop over them and add class to them

Answer (score 2):

you can use `className` when you want with pure Javascript try below code, otherwise with jQuery you can do the same easily.

```
//lets find the element with that class.
var menu = document.querySelectorAll('.megamenu');  

// lets verify only one menu with '.megamenu'
if(menu.length == 1)
{
  //set the class
  menu[0].className = " " + "anotherClassName";
}
```

**Update**

**We need to apply the class to the child of `megamenu`**

```
// lets verify only one menu with '.megamenu'
if(menu.length == 1)
{
  // set the class to the child '.container'
  // I'm expecting only one '.container' inside megamenu
  // if you have multiple and want apply for all use .querySelectorAll
  menu[0].querySelector('.container').className = " " + "anotherClassName";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your respond. It almost works but not exactly as I want.

Look structure of HTML
`<nav>`
`<ul>`
`<li>Menu Item 1</li>`
`<li class="megamenu">`
`<a href="#">Menu Item 2</a>`
`<ul class"container">`
`<li>Menu Item 1</li>`
`<li>Menu Item 1</li>`
`</ul>`
`</li>`
`<li>Menu Item 3</li>`
`</ul>`
`</nav>`

So you see there under `.megamenu` class `.container` this is where I want to be added if above class megamenu, sorry for a bit messed respond

Comment: so you mean you want to add the class to the `.container` which is the child of `.megamenu`??  that is also easy, np,  I will update answer, and if it will solve your problem, don't forget to mark this as an answer so will be helpful for other users too..